# not getting latest temperature from mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a TABLE with

```
ID,MasterID,beerline,temperature,temperaturetime,receivedtime
```

this is a table that gets a ID from the some hardware, with a beerline number and a temperature reading..

i'm trying to get MAX - MIN - CURRENT temperature reading from alle these lines with unique masterID and beerline

```
SELECT 
        MasterID,beerline, MAX(temperature) as max, MIN(temperature) as min, temperature 
FROM `temperatures` 
WHERE temperatures.MasterID IN 
        (SELECT masterdata.masterNo FROM masterdata WHERE masterdata.customerNo = '$customerID')
GROUP BY temperatures.beerline, temperatures.MasterID 
ORDER BY `receivedtime` DESC
```

This is not giving me the correct values at all, but can't get my head around what else i should try.

Sample data:

```
 MasterID beerline temperature temperaturetime receivedtime  
 - 5049      13         23   2017-10-24 13:24:00   2017-10-24 13:24:01
 - 5049      14         25   2017-10-24 13:24:00   2017-10-24 13:24:01
 - 4006      13         22   2017-10-24 13:22:55   2017-10-24 13:22:56
 - 4006      14         -1   2017-10-24 13:22:55   2017-10-24 13:22:56
 - 5049      13         23   2017-10-24 13:21:59   2017-10-24 13:22:01
 - 5049      14         23   2017-10-24 13:21:59   2017-10-24 13:22:01
 - 4006      13         22   2017-10-24 13:20:54   2017-10-24 13:20:56
 - 4006      14          0   2017-10-24 13:20:54   2017-10-24 13:20:56
 - 5049      13         20   2017-10-24 13:19:59   2017-10-24 13:20:00
 - 5049      14         23   2017-10-24 13:19:59   2017-10-24 13:20:00
 - 4006      14          0   2017-10-24 13:18:54   2017-10-24 13:18:55
 - 4006      13         22   2017-10-24 13:18:54   2017-10-24 13:18:55
```

What i want:

```
MasterID beerline temperature MAX(temperature) MIN(Temperature)
- 4006      13        22            22                22
- 4006      14        -1             0                -1
- 5049      13        23            23                20
- 5049      14        25            25                23
```

Here is my sqlfiddle :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e5abc/5/0

Comment: You added the current result only. Please add the sample data and desired result too

Comment: For most of your temperature data I am seeing a range in 20s.  If the min temperature is in the 20s why would expect to see 7C anywhere?

Comment: sorry for that, my min for one of the lines we are having in a fridge right now, gives me min 6,5 thats why i know the 22,5 is wrong

Comment: The way that you are using group by, and getting temprature at the same time is confusing for me honestly. I would try though putting temperature before Max(temperature) and Min(temperature) if you are intent on getting the max, min and temprature in one query. 
If it was up tome I'd use separate queries however. It is much cleaner

Comment: i'm having many master and they all have 1 to many beerlines.. so would like temperatures for all masters owned by this customer. and all the beerlines. thats why im grouping. maybe i should try with a JOIN instead.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the query itself, unless maybe the ORDER BY is doing something wrong.  Select temperatures and receivedtime for 4006 - 14 only and look at the raw data, you might notice something wrong there (date format in INSERT, sensor error, ...?)

Comment: only reason im not posting some sample data is because i can't make it look decent here on stackoverflow. but will try

Comment: its seems pretty clear to me that GROUP BY is messing with my result.. even when im trying to just get the temperature its giving me something wrong

Comment: Formatted the question hoping people will have better time understanding my question.